# Can't start elasticsearch server via Homebrew

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, elasticsearch, tire

So I have installed elasticsearch through brew:

```
$ brew install elasticsearch
```

Then when I run the elasticsearch server:

```
elasticsearch -f -D es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

I get this error:

```
{0.20.4}: Setup Failed ...
- FailedToResolveConfigException[Failed to resolve config path [/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/config/elasticsearch.yml], tried file path [/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/config/elasticsearch.yml], path file [/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.20.4/config/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/config/elasticsearch.yml], and classpath]
```

How can I fix this? Any ideas och suggestions are welcome.

**I did this and it had worked for me:**

Get the package:

```
$ curl -k -L -o elasticsearch-0.20.2.tar.gz http://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.20.2.tar.gz
```

Unzipp:

```
$ tar -zxvf elasticsearch-0.20.2.tar.gz
```

Run the elasticsearch server:

```
./elasticsearch-0.20.2/bin/elasticsearch -f
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try with

```
elasticsearch -f -Des.path.conf=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/0.19.3/config/
```

Comment: Also, have a look at `brew info elasticsearch` -- it should print information how to start/stop elasticsearch.

Answer (score 8):

That's weird, my install asked me to run elasticsearch slightly different.  I got it running with:

**Install**

```
$ brew update
$ brew install elasticsearch
```

**Run Elasticsearch**

```
$ elasticsearch --config=/usr/local/opt/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

As @karmi said, `brew info elasticsearch` shows how to run elasticsearch on your system.

Answer (score 1):

Things haven't been changed in 2021.

Homebrew stops distributing newer version of `elasticsearch`, and `kibana`, although you can still get outdated versions in `homebrew-core`.

It's beacause Homebrew defers to the OSI's open source licence definition. The new license used by elastic softwares is not compatible with it, and Homebrew rufuses to distribute them.

So, **elastic begins to distribute these software with its own custom tap**.

```sh
# tap maintained by elastic organization
# https://github.com/elastic/homebrew-tap
brew tap elastic/tap

brew install elastic/tap/elasticsearch-full
# brew install elastic/tap/kibina-full
# brew install elastic/tap/logstash-full
```